# How to create a dynamic view from button objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

**Hi**
I'm doing some objective-c projects and i'd like to know if there is a way to add a view from pushing a button.
I don't come out of the blue, i first tried to make a project with a view controller and 2 views where i can switch between both of them by pushing button. The fact is i had already create my 2 views..it works so i guess i'm not so far from the solution but...
Could anyone help me?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a view when pressing a button you should use:

```
UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

If you want to push a new viewcontroller you should use:

```
UIViewController* vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Let's supposed that i want to create a new view from my first view..do i have to create a new view controller in the view or can i create a new view without it?

Comment: You should make a new viewcontroller.